# Qt QNetworkReply readAll returns empty when request the same url again

Tags: c++, qt, url, qnetworkreply

This is for pure testing purpose and for my curiosity. I use my DataDownloader class to get a list of data from server. It works with different urls, like http://tiny-file-url, http://big-file-url. But if I pass in two identical urls, http://tiny-file-url, http://tiny-file-url, and the data from http://tiny-file-url is quite small, then the second reply from QNetworkAccessManager is empty. However two http://big-file-url seem to work. I'm wondering if QNetworkAccessManager does some magic when request small data from the same url? I can't seem to get any relevant information on Qt document site.

Here is my `DataDownloader` class:

```
class DataDownloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DataDownloader(QObject* parent = 0);
    virtual ~DataDownloader();

    QByteArray data() const;
    void cancel();
    void download(QUrl url);

    signals:
    void isComplete();

    private slots:
    void complete(QNetworkReply* reply);

    private:
    QNetworkAccessManager m_NetworkManager;
    QByteArray m_Data;
    QNetworkReply* m_pReply;
};

DataDownloader::DataDownloader(QUrl url, QObject* parent) :QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&m_NetworkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            SLOT(complete(QNetworkReply*)));
}

DataDownloader::~DataDownloader()
{
}

void DataDownloader::complete(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    // in the first download it returns data
    // but the second time m_Data is empty
    m_Data = reply->readAll();
    reply->deleteLater();

    if (!m_Data.isEmpty()) {
        // no signal on the second try
        emit isComplete();
    }
}

QByteArray DataDownloader::data() const
{
    return m_Data;
}

void DataDownloader::cancel()
{
    m_pReply->abort();
}

void DataDownloader::download(QUrl url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    m_pReply = m_NetworkManager.get(request);
}
```

The code that invokes this `DataDownloader` is as below:

```
void PluginManager::downloadPlugins()
{
    m_DownloadIndex++;

    savePlugin();

    if (m_DownloadIndex < m_PluginList.size()) {
        QUrl url;
        // alway return the same url here
        QString pluginUrl = getPluginUrl(m_PluginList.at(m_DownloadIndex));
        url.setUrl(pluginUrl);

        if (m_pPluginDownloader == NULL) {
            m_pPluginDownloader = new DataDownloader();
            // call this function again when isComplete is signaled
            connect(m_pPluginDownloader, SIGNAL(isComplete()), this, SLOT(downloadPlugins()));
        }
        m_pPluginDownloader->download(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Random code suggestion of the day: it's a much better idea to create only one `QNetworkAccessManager` instead of one per downloader.

Comment: BTW, are you 100% confident  http://tiny-file-url always works as expected?

Comment: I'm quite confident with it, since I can download the data as a file (containing debug text) and open it with an editor.

Comment: Sorry, if you mean if the actual tiny-file-url is working, it is just for illustration, it is not a valid url.

Comment: No, you got me, I meant your actual url :)

Answer (score 1):

I think here `isComplete` is emitted before you connect it to `downloadPlugins`slot. Try to first connect this signal and then do the download action :

```
m_pPluginDownloader = new DataDownloader(url);

connect(m_pPluginDownloader, SIGNAL(isComplete()), this, SLOT(downloadPlugins()));

m_pPluginDownloader.download();
```

Instead of performing get action in the constructor, do it in a slot called `download` :

```
void DataDownloader::download()
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    m_pReply = m_NetworkManager.get(request);
}
```

Another point is that it's not necessary to make a new instance of `DataDownloader`every time. You can create an instance in the constructor of `PluginManager` and connect `isComplete` signal once there. You can then provide the url as argument in `download` slot.

Comment: Hi Nejat, thank you for the reply. I have tried your suggestion, it works the same as before. I still get empty data on second download.

Comment: Hi Nejat, it seems this issue only happens to two identical url and the data from those urls are small. I'm going to test with two different urls that both contains small data to see if it make any difference.

Comment: So there are my test results: 
tiny-file-url, big-file-url   works
big-file-url, big-file-url   works
tiny-file-1-url, tiny-file-2-url   works
tiny-file-url, tiny-file-url   return empty on second request